# Banner Images not being reinserted correct to database

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When I update my banner_image it should delete the ones from the database Then re insert the ones that are set.

Currently what it does is deletes the banner image but then re inserts blank banner_image

But should remove that enitre row.

> **Question** How to make sure when I update it that will remove the images rows that are no longer selected and not re insert them

[image]

```
public function update($bid = NULL, $data = array()) {

$banner_update = array('banner_title' => $data['banner_title'], 'banner_status' => $data['banner_status']);

$this->db->where('bid', $bid);
$this->db->update('banner', $banner_update);

$this->db->where('bid', $bid)->delete('banner_image');

    if (isset($data['banner_image'])) {

        $banner_images = array();

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($data['banner_image'] as $image) {
            $banner_images[$i] = array(
                'bid' => $bid,
                'banner_image' => $image['image'],
            );

            $i++;
        }

        $this->db->insert_batch('banner_image', $banner_images);

    }

}
```

View

```
<?php echo form_open($action);?>
<div class="container">

    <div class="card mt-3">

    <div class="card-body">

    <?php if (validation_errors()) {?> 

    <?php unset($_POST);?>

    <div class="bg-error-warning">
    <ul>
    <?php echo validation_errors('<li>', '</li>');?>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <?php }?>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <p>Banner Title</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="banner_title" value="<?php echo $banner_title;?>" placeholder="Enter Banner Title" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <table id="images" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <button type="button" onclick="addImage();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Banner!" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <?php $image_row = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($banner_images as $banner_image) { ?>
            <tr id="image-row<?php echo $image_row; ?>">
                <td>
                <a href="" id="thumb-image<?php echo $image_row; ?>" data-toggle="image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $banner_image['thumb']; ?>" alt="" title="" data-placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" class="img-thumbnail"/></a>
                    <input type="hidden" name="banner_image[<?php echo $image_row; ?>][image]" value="<?php echo $banner_image['image']; ?>" id="input-image<?php echo $image_row; ?>" />
              </td>
            </tr>

            <?php $image_row++; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>

    </table>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <p>Banner Status</p>
        <div class="form-group">

            <?php $options = array('0' => 'Disabled', '1' => 'Enabled'); echo form_dropdown('banner_status', $options, $banner_status, array('class' => 'form-control'));?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-dark">Create Banner</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var image_row = <?php echo $image_row; ?>;  

function addImage() {
html  = '<tr id="image-row' + image_row + '">';
html += '<td class="text-left">';
html += '<a href="" id="thumb-image' + image_row + '" data-toggle="image" >';
html += '<img src="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" width="100" height="100" class="img-thumbnail" data-placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>"/>';
html += '<input type="hidden" name="banner_image[' + image_row + '][image]" value="" id="input-image' + image_row + '" />'
html += '</a>';
html += '</td>';

html += '<td class="text-left">';
html += '<button type="button" onclick="$(\'#image-row' + image_row  + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove Banner!" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>'
html += '</td>';

html += '<script>';
html += '$(document).ready(function(){';
html += '$(\'[data-toggle="tooltip"]\').tooltip();';
html += '});';
html += '<\/script>';

$('#images tbody').append(html);

image_row++;

}

</script>
```

Comment: Why do you update, delete, and insert again with the same id?

Comment: @RyukLee Because there may be new banners and plus any old ones that have been removed need to be deleted. I have solved it any way with my answer below just need to use `!empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have got it working just had to put empty in the foreach loop

```
public function update($bid = NULL, $data = array()) {

    $banner_update = array('banner_title' => $data['banner_title'], 'banner_status' => $data['banner_status']);

    // Updates the main banner table
    $this->db->where('bid', $bid);
    $this->db->update('banner', $banner_update);

    // Removes banners so can have clean insert of new banners selected
    $this->db->where('bid', $bid);
    $this->db->delete('banner_image');

    // Inserts new banner images & saved ones.
    if ($this->input->post('banner_image')) {
        foreach ($this->input->post('banner_image') as $image) {
            if (!empty($image['image'])) {
                $this->db->insert('banner_image', array('bid' => $bid, 'banner_image' => $image['image']));
            }
        }
    }
}
```